# Using sound frequency as a driver

Tags: drivers, audio

I am trying to do an animation where I want to use the frequency of sound as a driver instead of the amplitude. I have already done a couple of experiments using the bake sound to curves but that deals only with amplitude of the said frequency range.
I have a virtual theremin sound that I would like my mesh to respond to so that a higher pitch would drive the mesh more than a lower pitch.
Is this possible in blender? Are there any add-ons or things that can be used in blender that extract the frequency data for using as a driver?
I am not conversant with python so am more or less dependant on basic animation techniques.
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at animation nodes. This add-on is free and can do such things.

Comment: Thank you very much.